# Cannot Resolve R in Android Studio . Tried all the standard solutions

Tags: android

I cannot Resolve R: Here is what my Code look like which is posted in a screenshot.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

The first solution I tried was: Going to Build and Rebuild, that didn't seemed to work.

The second solution was: Tools==>Android==>Sync Project with Gradle Files.

None of those solutions worked. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Please read your error, coincedently you are highlighting the error :)

Answer (score 4):

> What do you guys suggest?

Well, the error tells you exactly what the problem is. `dog shirt.jpg` has an invalid character (a space, it looks like). Rename that file to use lowercase letters (`a` through `z`), digits (`0` through `9`), and underscores for the base name (the part before the `.jpg`).

Comment: Fixed that and totally removed the jpg file with the space in between.

Now I am getting this error:

"Error:(22, 35) String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'wrap_content ')."

I don't understand that since layout_width allows wrap_content.

Comment: Here is a link:  [link]http://217.199.187.200/pentaworld.com/Capture.JPG _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: Should I ask a new question in order to have my latest question answered

Comment: @JanePoe It seems you like **spaces** a lot... `with value 'wrap_content '` you have a space after `"wrap_content"`. Which is not allowed.